# Two network interfaces (eth0 and eth1) of same linux machine can't ping each other

Tags: linux, networking

I have one Linux machine having two gigabit network interface. I want to run the traffic test such as `iperf` on two interfaces: eth0 will be server and eth1 will be client. I connected back-to-back network cables (between eth0 and eth1) and configured the ip address

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 up

ifconfig eth1 192.168.0.11 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Now i am trying to ping from eth0 to eth1 using following command:

```
ping -I eth0 192.168.0.11
```

but ping is not working, so I tried `tcpdump`

```
tcpdump -i eth0
```

which says ARP request is reaching to eth1—but eth1 doesn't reply

I tried another way also using

```
ping -I eth1 192.168.0.10
```

but it is also not working

```
arp -a
```

command says incomplete, so I am wondering why this is not working, i tried this same configuration in Ubuntu and CentOS. but no luck. 
The `/etc/hosts` file is not configured—is it required? I already tried using straight as well as cross cable.

Comment: Are you using a crossover cable?

Comment: Is your `hosts` file configured?

Comment: is "netamsk" in your 2nd ifconfig line a copy/paste typo or a real one?

Comment: Having two interfaces in the same /24 network on one machine won't work. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried using crossover as well as straight cable, but it is not working. hosts file is not configured. Is it required? Also netamsk is typo in the eth1 configuration while sending the post. I have not enabled the ip_forward it is 0 in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward. Also what i am trying to achieve is to run traffic test between two ethernet port.

Comment: save the iptables to a file, try flushing the iptables and check again, I'm having a similar type of problem and I'm all over trying iptables without success.

Answer (score 2):

This can work, but is not a normal configuration. If you want services within a server to talk via multiple IP addresses consider using multiple loop back interfaces, EG lo0 127.0.0.1, lo1 127.0.0.2. That eliminates bandwidth and physical layer issues.

That said, if the ICMP echo request is being sent and received, but not replied to, that suggests a firewall issue. Double check that no firewall rules are blocking it, possibly via flushing iptables temporarily.

Comment: i tried even shutting down the iptable service using  "service iptables stop" command but even that did not help.

Comment: Any reason your services can't run on an ip address that uses the local loopback?  127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, etc